# Laravel: Loop through results on a 12 column bootstrap grid with different sizes

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap

Inside a foreach loop of products, I want to display each of the elements in unequal/uneven column sizes that make up a total of 12 just like what we have in the screenshot below. How can I achieve this in Laravel?

[image]

Comment: Have you made something yourself that we can help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the `col` to each product in controller:

```
$cols = [3, 9, 3, 6, 3, 6, 6];
foreach($products as $key => $product){
    $product->col = $cols[$key % count($cols)];
}
```

Blade:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
<div class="col-{{ $product->col }}"></div>
@endforeach
```